# how to add quote mark over a variable value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I having a variable data `firstSelectedColumn.Name` and I want to put quote mark, the code below throws a runtime error:

```
 upRequested: function () {
        selectedItems = this.requestedSelected; 
        firstSelectedColumn = selectedItems.shift();
        //whats wrong here???????????
        requestedSelected: ko.observableArray(['@firstSelectedColumn.Name']);
        }
    },
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: How is this related to jquery?

Comment: @user584018 Do you want to print "firstSelectedColumn.Name"?

Comment: the value of firstSelectedColumn.Name = "abc"....In RAZOR...I want to put quote mark before and after abc like 'abc' like....requestedSelected: ko.observableArray(['abc'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       requestedSelected: ko.observableArray([firstSelectedColumn.Name]);
```

It's not razor since this is only client side code and I see no server side code here which razor is used for.